# Maximum overlap of two convex bodies

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, symmetry, combinatorial-geometry

Let $\Delta_n=\big\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n): \sum_i x_i \leq 1, x_i \geq 0\big\}$ denote an n-dimensional simplex. I am trying to find an $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the $y-$shifted negative simplex has maximum overlap with $\Delta_n$. Formally:

$$
\max_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}\  \text{vol} (\Delta_n \cap (-\Delta_n+y))
$$

I wrote the volume as an integral of indicator function , but I don't know how to maximize that integral in n-dimensions.

Comment: i would play with it in 2- and 3-D and see if you get any insight

Comment: @gt6989b: In 2-D it's turning out be $(1/2,1/2)$. In 3-D also I believe it's true and trying to generalize if it's $(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$ in higher dimensions.

Comment: i am assuming you proved this with maximizing the integration - any insight from 2D and 3D we can use for the general form? Perhaps enough for an inductive argument?